# Does static XML Serializer in C# cause memory over grow?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, methods, static

I just can't find a simple answer to this simple question I have from Dr Google. I have the following serializing function which I put in a static module. It is called many times by my application to serialize lots of XML files. Will this cause memory to over grow? (Ignore the text write part of the code)

```
public static void SerializeToXML<T>(String inFilename,T t) 
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
    string FullName = inFilename;
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(FullName);
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, t); 
    textWriter.Close();
    textWriter.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will this cause memory to over grow?

No. There will be no memory over growing. `static` will let you call `SerializeToXML` method without create a new instance of the class. Not anything else.

So if you're calling this method many times, You even shrinking the memory usage with a `static` method.

Though you wrote to ignore the text write part, You should use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for unmanaged resources:

```
public static void SerializeToXML<T>(String inFilename,T t) 
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());
    string FullName = inFilename;
    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(FullName))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, t); 
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the "XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(t.GetType());" I'm creating a new instance for each call

Comment: @user1034912. The garbage collection will dispose it, Only the method is static.

Comment: so do you need to call the garbage collector often?

Comment: @user1034912. Everything is done automatically, In almost all situations you can ignore it's existence.

Comment: Thanks, but how does it know I'm still not using that memory object?

Comment: @user1034912. Because you have no live reference to it. read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) please.